# Retrofit 2.0 post request

Tags: android, api, retrofit2

Hello I am trying to implement Post request using Retrofit 2.0

My Question is that show Should I write in onResponse so as to get data by taking input from the user or manually.

Thank you

Comment: Where are you calling `createCards()`?

Comment: You might want to move ``postCards`` into a Loader object as your response may arrive in an older activity instance and cause a memory leak while it is being processed.

Answer (score 1):

for post method you have to use @Body tags in interface

```
@POST("/api/Cards")
Call<List<Card>> createCards(@Body List<Card> cards);
```

and call from activity

```
Card card=new Card();
card.setId(20);
card.setTitle("New Cards");
card.setMessage("New Launched cards");

List<Card> cards=new List<Card>();
cards.add(card);
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    RequestApi requestApi = retrofit.create(RequestApi.class);
    mCardsRequest = requestApi.createCards(cards);
    mCardsRequest.enqueue(new Callback<List<Card>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Card>> call, Response<List<Card>> response) {
            ** what should I add here to post data **   
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Card>> call, Throwable t) {
            //
        }
    });
```

Comment: put Log.d("tags",t.toString); in the onFailure method and tell me the error

Answer (score 0):

`onResponse` is called AFTER the request completes.  You wouldn't be asking for user's input in this reverse order (unless you are doing multiple requests or chaining them).  So you should already have user's input PRIOR to making the Retrofit request.

So your **onResponse** callback is where you process the http response:

```
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<Card>> call, Response<List<Card>> response) {
        processResponse(response.body());
    }
```

But before you send the request (and receive the response), you can add form data to your **POST** request, you can do something like:

```
@POST("/api/Cards")
Call<List<Card>> createCards(@Body List<Card> cards,
        // Sort the cards using a query string param
        @Query("sort") String contractAccount),
        // Set a group id parameter as the replacement block
        @Path("id") int groupId);
```

Comment: can you explain how to to that@Igor Ganapolsky